Word problem involving arithmetic sequence: need to find the last possible nth term and what that term produces.
"A child builds with blocks, placing 35 blocks in the first row, 31 in the second row, 27 in the third row, and so on. Continuing this pattern, can he end with a row containing exactly 1 block? If not, how many blocks will the last row contain? How many rows can he build this way?"
I know I can simply deduct 4 from 35 and count down but considering that the textbook chapter is basically introducing the subject of arithmetic sequence and all the questions for that section involve arithmetic sequences, I am pretty sure the book wants me to use the general term of an arithmetic sequence.
So, I need to solve for a-sub-n.
I have the common difference as (-4) and the initial amount of 35.
How do I proceed?

I suggest:  first do the problem by force, as you suggest.  Then you'll know the answer and can try to prove it more elegantly. Toward that end, I suggest trying to spot patterns in the numbers.  Or, simply write down the form of the $n^{th}$ number algebraically and see if you can solve for an $n$ that gives you $1$.

Well.  $a_1=35$ and $a_{k+1} = a_k -4$ and common sense/induction/looking a formula in a book we can generalize that $a_n = 35 - 4(n-1)$.  So we need to know if $a_n = 35-4(n-1) = 1; n\in \mathbb N$ is possible to solve.

"I have the common difference as (-4) and the initial amount of 35."  So what does the text say about how to express that as a sequence?  The book probably has a formula.  If not you can play around with it and guess what the formula is (Hint: It is really simple with no tricks!)

.... so in the $n$th you you have gone from the first row to the $n$th row.  How many differences in rows is that?  And each row you decrease by fotr and so you to go that many times you have decrease how many times?  So you start and $a_1=35$ and you decrease by $4$ that many times.... so the formula is what?

The $n$-th row will contain $35-4(n-1)$ blocks. Could it be that $$35-4(n-1)=1?$$ In this case we get $$n=\frac{35-1}4+1.$$ But this number is not integer, so it can’t be.
The $n$-th row is still not empty, if $$35-4(n-1)\ge0$$
$$n\le \frac{35}4+1=9\frac34.$$
Since $n$ is integer, we have that maximal $n$ equals $9$. So there are $9$ rows, and $$35-4\cdot8=3$$ blocks in the last row.

$A_n=a+(n-1)d$
In case of decreasing, the $d$ becomes negative. For every $n^{th}$ attachment of blocks, the number of blocks decrease by $4\implies$ increase by $(-4)$ times $(n-1)$.
We assume that we are able to reach $1$. So
$$1=35+(n-1)(-4) \implies n=\frac{19}{2}=9.5$$
This isn't possible, there can't be $9$ and a "half" turns, and it's impossible for him to add more $4$ blocks. Thus maximum times he can add the blocks is $9$, and he will have $35+(9-1)(-4)=3$ bricks left on the last row.

Another way to look at it is that  $35\div 4$   doesn't give a whole number, there will be a remainder of $3$, and every time we reduce the number by $4$, the remainder will still remain $3$
So the final (positive) term must be $3$. it can't be $1$
And now that we know the starting term, common difference and final term, we can easily compute $n$
